# Issue when change the password via admin account

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, admin-panel

When I go to the `admin -> System -> My Account` and change the password when save it show the error

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_System_AccountController::_validateCurrentPassword() in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/AccountController.php` on line 73
Please help me resolve this issue.
My Magento Version: **Magento ver. 1.9.0.1.**

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`_validateCurrentPassword()` should be define in `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php`) which `Mage_Adminhtml_System_AccountController` extends

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_System_AccountController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
```

Try downloading a new copy and diff both files.

Answer (score 0):

@Manashvi,
Thanks for your answered. I'm tried to add this function to end the file: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php

```
/**
 * Validate password for current admin user
 *
 * @param string $password - current password
 *
 * @return mixed - returns true or array of errors
*/
protected function _validateCurrentPassword($password)
{
    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
    return $user->validateCurrentPassword($password);
}
```

And it's working fine now.
Thanks again @Manashvi birla